# How to make class return other type without getter?

Tags: c++, class

My Code:

```
class MyWindowSettings {

public:

    const ofGLFWWindowSettings& get(){
        return settings;
    }

private:
    ofGLFWWindowSettings settings;
};
```

How can I use this class for functions that require `ofGLFWWindowSettings` instead of `MyWindowSettings` without the getter?

Currently I do

```
MyWindowSettings settings;
ofCreateWindow(settings.get());
```

But I would like to do like the following instead

```
MyWindowSettings settings;
ofCreateWindow(settings);
```

How can I do this?

Comment: So you want a *type conversion operator*? Don't overuse them though, as they can make the code less readable and therefore less maintainable.

Comment: Another option is to use inheritance: `class MyWindowSettings : public ofGLFWWindowSettings { ... }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what you probably what to do is use the [user-defined convertion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) operator

```
class MyWindowSettings {

public:

    operator const ofGLFWWindowSettings&(){
        return settings;
    }

private:
    ofGLFWWindowSettings settings;
};
```

Comment: Probably worth adding a caveat that user-defined conversion operators and non-explicit single-argument constructors (particularly when used in combination) can have surprising results.  Thus `std::string` has an implicit constructor from `const char *`, but requires an explicit getter (`.c_str()`) to go in the other direction.